# Flatten a list of arbitrary depth in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out how to flatten a list of n arbitrary depth in Haskell. Right now my function looks like:

```
data NestedList a = Regular [a] | Nested [NestedList a]

flatten::(Num a, Eq a)=> NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Regular as) = as
flatten (Nested as) = concatMap flatten as
```

But then I try to invoke it:

```
*Main> flatten [1,2,3,[1,[1,2]],2]
```

I get this error message:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘NestedList a’
                  with actual type ‘[[[Integer]]]’
    • In the first argument of ‘flatten’, namely
        ‘[1, 2, 3, [1, [1, 2]], ....]’
      In the expression: flatten [1, 2, 3, [1, [1, 2]], ....]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = flatten [1, 2, 3, ....]
    • Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:25:1)
```

I haven't programmed in Haskell in quite son time so I can't really remember how to fix this error, or if my function is just plain wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You did not use a `NestedList` when you call this with `flatten`.

Comment: To expand on @WillemVanOnsem’s advice, you need to do `flatten (Nested [Regular [1], Regular [2], Regular [3], Nested [Regular [1], Nested [Regular [1], Regular [2]]], Regular [2]])` instead. I would also advise you to change the `Regular [a]` constructor to `Regular a`, so you can represent non-nested lists as `Nested [Regular 1, Regular 2, Regular 3]`.

Comment: Okay, I get it now! Do you know if there is another way for me to make a function where I would simply have to input `[1,2,3,[1,[1,2]],2]` and get `[1,2,3,1,1,2,2]`as a return value? Should I look to `Trees` for this?

Comment: @Grebalb: You can use an `OverloadedList` extension: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/overloaded-lists

Comment: @Grebalb Without using `OverloadedLists` as recommended by WillemVanOnsem, there really is no way to do this: a list `[a]` must have every element the same type `a`, but your list would have to have some elements of type `a` and some elements of type `[a]`.

Comment: How would you go about doing it with `OverloadedLists`?

Comment: @bradrn I tried changing `Regular [a]` to `Regular a`, but get the exception: `Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          flatten :: forall a. NestedList a -> [a]`. Any idea?

Comment: @Grebalb If you change the definition of `NestedList`, you also need to modify `flatten` to work with the new definition.

Comment: Solved it. Did you know of a way to make the expression easier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not construct a nested list, but a "simple" list. Furthermore the definition of the nested list, does not really allow to write the list you describe, you can wrap the elements in singleton lists, but that will make it more complicated.

You can implement such nested list as:

```
data NestedList a = Leaf a | Nested [NestedList a]
```

If you use the [**`-XDeriveFoldable`** option](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFoldable) you do not even need to implement `flatten` yourself, but can let Haskell do the work for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data NestedList a = Leaf a | Nested [NestedList a] deriving Foldable
```

Then we can call this with:

```
import Data.Foldable

toList (Nested [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Leaf 3, Nested [Leaf 1,Nested [Leaf 1, Leaf 2]], Leaf 2])
```

For the given sample list, this gives us:

```
Prelude Data.Foldable> toList (Nested [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Leaf 3, Nested [Leaf 1,Nested [Leaf 1, Leaf 2]], Leaf 2])
[1,2,3,1,1,2,2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if there is a technique where I would be able to simply input a "simple list" like I did and get an un-nested version of it back? Should I look to `Trees` for this?

Comment: @Grebalb: you can use `OverloadedLists` to make it more convenient, but I think it will still use some data constructors, but I think you will still need to write the `Nested` for example.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to go through the list when it is first entered and construct a Nested LIst out of the input? And then simply passing it through this function to flatten it?